# Maven build order

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module maven build and I need one particular module (lets call it project-A) to be build at the end. It depends on a module (lets call it project-B) that holds native code that gets compiled to a dll and installed into the maven repository as a zip file using some maven trickery. As it doesn't depends on it directly because the native code is not a java jar, I use Maven Dependency Plugin to unpack the zip file and place the native dll in my build directory. Everything is working fine except for the building order. It builds first project-A in spite of being declared the other way around in the  tag in the parent. I would like to tell maven that project-A depends on project-B. I tried to add project-B as a dependency, but as it builds no jar it throws an ERROR, also this seemed hacky to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare dependency in project A to project B and it will work fine. It does not matter if the project B is a native rather than a java project. Just make sure you declare the dependency correctly taking the packaging into account as type.. (which is probably `pom` so you would have

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>B</artifactId>
  <version>...</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

in Project A)

Comment: I was missing the <type> tag, after that, I could manage the reactor order. Project B is a module that contains a bunch of projects, I had to add them one by one. Is there a way in which I can only refer to the parent instead of each of the projects individually?

Comment: You should add the dependencies how the code dictates it and now how your build/module setup makes it seem convenient. Then things will work just fine and with clean dependencies in your code your project setup will be clean too ;-)

Comment: Also the type might be something else like so or bin depending on how your native code build is set up. And if project b is a parent you should probably not declare a dependency to it but rather to the modules you actually depend on like you did..

Answer (score 1):

The order in which you specify the modules in the parent Pom is also relevant. Maven actually builds in this order unless it has to build a module out of sequence due to direct dependencies.

Comment: That is what I thought, but that wasn't doing the trick, now it is working fine, but I had to add each project as a dependency. I don't know why the Maven Reactor was ignoring the order in the modules tags if no dependency between the projects was explicit.